# css and html list or div position with or without thumbnails

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, position

I have a page which will display our expertise in several topics.
Each topic contains a header, image, and a short list.
Inside of the page the user is to see the topic thumbnail image & headers for all topics,
They will also see 1 highlighted topic in it's entirety (header, full image, and list).  The highlighted topic is iterated through and the user can wand over topic headers to change the highlighted one.
the html for each topic is generated in rails using a partial so each topic is managed as separate files.

I have a working solution but there are some issues with it I'd like some direction on.
[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/twinturbotom/U68Wg/)

Thanks for the time!

1. CSS & HTML issues... should my 6 topics be in a list like now or as 6 divs?  My right and left columns don't respond the same: change the top level div width (.showScene between 680 to 1000px) and you'll see the right column text is centered instead of staying justified to the right images.  How should the CSS look?
   My general strategy for lists is to use :nth-child sectors to create and control columns with left and right floats in this case.
2. My 'thumbnail' is the large image using css to re-size, is that okay or do I really need to create a thumbnail sized image?  Each large image appears on the page so why load a bunch more thumbnails?  If i did use a thumbnail I would then have to add it to my topic with the large image?
3. I use the jQuery .clone() to copy content into my highlighted pane, is that the best way?  I hate duplicating but without clone the header and thumbnail is "moved out"

CSS:

```
.showScene{width: 1000px; border: 2px solid black; height: 400px; position: absolute;}
#exp {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#exp > h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 2px;

       color: #669900;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: #669900;

}

#exp > ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*width: 700px;*/
    margin-top: -20px;

}
#exp > ul > li {
      float:left;
      width:30%;
      height: 120px;
      padding-top: 6px;
      padding-bottom: 6px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: .8em;
}
#exp > ul > li img{
      width:30%;
      vertical-align: middle;
}
#exp > ul > li:nth-child(odd){
    margin-left: 3%;
}
#exp > ul > li:nth-child(odd) img{
    padding-right:10px;
}
#exp > ul > li:nth-child(even){
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10%;
}
#exp > ul > li:nth-child(even) h1{
    text-align: right;
}
#exp > ul > li:nth-child(even) img{
    position: relative;
    left: 95%;
}
.expSelected h1{
    color: #669900;
}
#expPane .expSelected  h1 {
    color: black;
}
.expList ul li {
    display:none;
}
.expList h1{
    font-size: 1.25em;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 80px;
}
.expList img {
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#expPane{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left:30%;
    right: 30%;
    height: 250px;
}
#expPane img{
    height: 100px;
}
#expPane .expList{
    width: 272px;
    margin: auto;
}
#expPane .expList ul li{
    display: list-item;
}
#expPane h1 {
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
#expPane img {
    float:none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 225px;
}
#expPane ul {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class='sliderContent'>
    <ul>
        <li><div class='showScene'>
                <div id='exp'>
                    <h1>Our Expertise</h1>
                        <ul>
                            <li><div class='expList topic1'>
                                    <h1>Topic1 Header</h1>
                                    <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uq1xArFbmAE/T5GjNmF-c7I/AAAAAAAAGNY/oRT4dS0y6Ic/s1600/Cool-Pictures1.jpg'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>key1</li>
                                        <li>key2</li>
                                        <li>key3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><div class='expList topic2'>
                                    <h1>Topic2 Header</h1>
                                    <img src='http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-y_A2TCaEnZU/TxzbuvYiNhI/AAAAAAAAAZ4/fuMGkV3FEak/s1600/Cool.jpg'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>key1</li>
                                        <li>key2</li>
                                        <li>key3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><div class='expList topic3'>
                                    <h1>Topic3 Header</h1>
                                    <img src='http://www.remodelpros.com/spaw/uploads/images/mr-roof-smiling.png'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>key1</li>
                                        <li>key2</li>
                                        <li>key3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>            

                            <li><div class='expList topic4'>
                                    <h1>Topic4 Header</h1>
                                    <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uq1xArFbmAE/T5GjNmF-c7I/AAAAAAAAGNY/oRT4dS0y6Ic/s1600/Cool-Pictures1.jpg'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>key1</li>
                                        <li>key2</li>
                                        <li>key3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li><div class='expList topic5'>
                                    <h1>Topic5 Header</h1>
                                    <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uq1xArFbmAE/T5GjNmF-c7I/AAAAAAAAGNY/oRT4dS0y6Ic/s1600/Cool-Pictures1.jpg'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>key1</li>
                                        <li>key2</li>
                                        <li>key3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>             
                            <li><div class='expList topic6'>
                                    <h1>Topic6 Header</h1>
                                    <img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-uq1xArFbmAE/T5GjNmF-c7I/AAAAAAAAGNY/oRT4dS0y6Ic/s1600/Cool-Pictures1.jpg'>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>key1</li>
                                        <li>key2</li>
                                        <li>key3</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </li>   

                        </ul>
                                            <div id='expPane'></div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var actual = 1;

$(document).ready(function() {

    /* get all 'src' */
    links = $('#exp > ul > li > div');

    /* set first image */
    imgFirst(links);

    /* iterate images */
    startExp();
    /* hover images */
    imgHov();


});
/* set first image */
function imgFirst(links) {
    $('#expPane').html($(links[0]).clone());
};
//set interval
function startExp(){
    i = 0;
    startExpVar = setInterval(function() {
        imgIterate(links);
    }, 3000);
}
//stop interval
function stopExp(){
    clearInterval(startExpVar);
}
/* iterate images */
function imgIterate(links) {
    $('#expPane').fadeOut('slow', function(){
        ++i;
        if (i >= links.length){i = 0}
        $('#expPane').html($(links[i]).clone()).fadeIn('slow');
    });
};

/* hover images */
function imgHov() {
    links.hover(function() {
        var activeOne = $(this);
        activeOne.addClass('expSelected');
        stopExp();
        $('#expPane').fadeOut('fast', function(){
            $('#expPane').html(activeOne.clone()).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }, function() {
        imgIterate(links);
        startExp();
        $(this).removeClass('expSelected');

    });
}
```

Comment: That's kind of my point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I think the current setup you have seems to work fine, very easy to determine what is part of the list vs what isn't (easier to just look in a UL than find divs contained in wrapperX or with a given class).
2. You don't HAVE to create thumbnails, but I consider it a generally good idea.  You can get some distortion or graininess when doing it through CSS at times.
3. Clone seems legit

Comment: Thanks for the look, I'll keep the lists and clone and see if I will trade laziness for graininess on making thumbs work.  The way I'm splitting the list for the right headers and images irritates me on resizing; I may make most of that resizing happen with jQuery over css, what do you thinks? Thanks again!